# Type inheritance in function arguments

Tags: function, inheritance, arguments, julia

I'm having an issue with type in functions, I've managed to write the minimal code that explains the problem:

```
immutable Inner{B<:Real, C<:Real}
a::B
c::C
end

immutable Outer{T}
    a::T
end

function g(a::Outer{Inner})
    println("Naaa")
end

inner = Inner(1, 1)
outer = Outer(inner)

g(outer)
```

Will lead to the method error

    `MethodError: no method matching g(::Outer{Inner{Int64,Int64}})`

So basically, I don't want to have to say what the types of Inner are, I just want the function to make sure that it's an `Outer{Inner}` and not `Outer{Float64}` or something.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not sure, but I think that `g` should be defined as `function g(a::Outer{<:Inner})` (with a `<:`), since `Inner{Int64,Int64}` is not a subtype of `Inner{Real, Real}` (see the documentation at [Parametric Composite Type](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Parametric-Composite-Types-1))

Comment: THANK YOU!
yes that works, if you're into stack overflow points just write an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `Inner{Int64,Int64}` is a concrete `Inner` type and it is not a subtype of
`Inner{Real, Real}`, since different concrete types of `Inner` (Int64 or Float64)
can have different representations in memory.

According to the documentation, function `g` should be defined as:

```
function g(a::Outer{<:Inner})
    println("Naaa")
end
```

so it can accept all arguments of type `Inner`.

Some examples, after define `g` with `<:`:

```
# -- With Float32 --

julia> innerf32 = Inner(1.0f0, 1.0f0)
Inner{Float32,Float32}(1.0f0, 1.0f0)

julia> outerf32 = Outer(innerf32)
Outer{Inner{Float32,Float32}}(Inner{Float32,Float32}(1.0f0, 1.0f0))

julia> g(outerf32)
Naaa

# -- With Float64 --

julia> innerf64 = Inner(1.0, 1.0)
Inner{Float64,Float64}(1.0, 1.0)

julia> outerf64 = Outer(innerf64)
Outer{Inner{Float64,Float64}}(Inner{Float64,Float64}(1.0, 1.0))

julia> g(outerf64)
Naaa

# -- With Int64 --

julia> inneri64 = Inner(1, 1)
Inner{Int64,Int64}(1, 1)

julia> outeri64 = Outer(inneri64)
Outer{Inner{Int64,Int64}}(Inner{Int64,Int64}(1, 1))

julia> g(outeri64)
Naaa
```

More details at the documentation: [Parametric Composite Type](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Types)

---

***Update***: The way to declare an immutable composite type (as in the original question), have changed to:

```
struct Inner{B<:Real, C<:Real}
    a::B
    c::C
end

struct Outer{T}
    a::T
end
```

Furthermore, function `g` could be declared with a parametric type:

```
function g(a::T) where T Outer{<:Inner}
    println(a)
    println(a.a)
    println(a.c)
end
```

And hence, there is no need to create an instance of `Outer` before calling the function.

```
julia> ft64 = Inner(1.1, 2.2)
Inner{Float64,Float64}(1.1, 2.2)

julia> g(ft64)
Inner{Float64,Float64}(1.1, 2.2)
1.1
2.2

julia> i64 = Inner(3, 4)
Inner{Int64,Int64}(3, 4)

julia> g(i64)
Inner{Int64,Int64}(3, 4)
3
4
```