# Generic Numeric Arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, types, julia

I'm trying to learn Julia by reading the documentation, and they have code that looks like this:

```
function testFunction(x::Number)
    return x+5
end
```

This is a function that works for any of the many numeric types in Juila.

However, if I attempt to do something similar, like this:

```
function testFunction2(x::Array{Number})
    return x
end
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching testFunction2(::Array{Int64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  testFunction2(::Array{Number,N} where N) at /Users/.../Desktop/Test.jl:45
```

Am I doing something wrong? I thought this: `Array{Float64}` is how you declare an array of a specific type, yet using a type like `Number`, which works for the regular case, doesn't work here... Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: `testFunction2` should be declared: `function testFunction2(x::Array{<:Number})` (with `<:`), since *Array{Float64}* is not a subtype of *Array{Number}*. See: [Type inheritance in function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907220/type-inheritance-in-function-arguments/49909035)

Comment: Julia's type system is *invariant*. This is covered in detail in [this section of the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Parametric-Types-1) (in particular, see the highlighted warning)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition

```
function testFunction2(x::Array{Number})
    return x
end
```

is the identify function that accepts as input an `Array{Number}`. So the following will work:

`testFunction2(collect((1,3,-2.7,5+2im)))`

but this will *not* work:

`testFunction2([1,3,7,9])`

This can be seen from here:

```
julia> typeof(collect((1,3,-2.7,5+2im)))
Array{Number,1}

julia> typeof([1,3,7,9])
Array{Int64,1}
```

The first matches the type of `x` in your definition of `testFunction2` and the second does not. (Note that `Array{Number}` is synonymous for `Array{Number,1}`.)

What you are looking for is a function that accepts an array of any element type which is a subtype of `Number`. This is done as:

```
function testFunction2(x::Array{T}) where {T<:Number}
    return x
end
```

where now we have a parameter `T` that is allowed to be any subtype of `Number`. You also get to use the sugar

```
function testFunction2(x::Array{<:Number})
    return x
end
```

or even `testFunction2(x::Array{<:Number}) = x`.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the other answer: the reason there is a difference in behaviour between the example in the manual and your code is that in your case, `Number` is used as the type parameter in another type (`Array`). That gets stricter type checks than if `Number` was used as the type by itself. As @StefanKarpinski says in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21466091/8127),

> This is a consequence of parametric type invariance in Julia. See the [chapter on types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types.html#Parametric-Types-1) in the manual for more details.

(Link corrected to be current.)

The key point from the manual is: "even though Float64 <: Real we DO NOT have Point{Float64} <: Point{Real}." Similarly in your case, even though we have `Int64 <: Number`, we **do not** have `Array{Int64} <: Array{Number}`, which is why the type matching fails.

So in general, you *can* write `x::Number` to match any number type, you can write `p::AbstractString` to match any string type that's a subtype of `AbstractString`, etc. But if you're using the abstract type as a type parameter as part of another type, then you have to specify explicitly that you want it to match all subtypes of the parameter type i.e. with `Point{<:Real}` or `Array{<:Number}`.

Comment: +1, I should have pointed out the parametric type invariance in comparison to `f(x::Number)` which would allow `f(1)`, `f(2+3im)` etc.